# Cannot find local variable in Android Java

Tags: java, android

Hello I am using Java to code an android app and I am getting a bug where the program doesn't think that the variable 'sc' exists.

```
    SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    sc.init(null, getTrustingManager(), new java.security.SecureRandom());

    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
    socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(sc);
    Scheme sch = new Scheme("https", socketFactory, 443);
    client.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(sch);
```

I have a hunch that my issue is with creating a new object changes the scope so that 'sc' can't be seen.

Comment: where is `sc` declared ? in the local scope of a method ?

Comment: Make "sc"final variable

Comment: @Blackbelt you can see in this code where sc is declared it's the first line.

Comment: I can see six lines of *code*.

Comment: @NilayDani final didn't solve the issue

        `final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");`

Comment: @Blackbelt To clarify all 6 of these lines are inside of the same method. So I didn't exclude any code.

Comment: Any try/catch blocks that you're not showing us?

Comment: @schtever This is all the code for this method so all the exceptions are handled in the method declaration.

Comment: What source line does the error point to?  One of the lines shown above?

Comment: Oops. Guess the final did it and then I had another error so I didn't notice that the local variable problem had been fixed. Thanks @NilayDani !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

to

```
final SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
```

fixed the error. Thanks again NilayDani.